# pickadate input trigger to add class name on div title

Tags: jquery, pickadate

we are using http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ plugin for our development.

Solution needed: when i clicked input field, it have add class 'displayTitle' on 'date_title'. But, its not triggering first time. some time 2nd trigger.. some time have to click multiple times to add class name.

Please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fieldset date_departure">
    <div class="date_title">Departure date</div>
    <div class="input-append merge-right">
        <input type="text" class="date_textbox dateDeparture" id="dateDeparture" placeholder="Departure date">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.dateDeparture').click(function(){
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).addClass('dateFocused');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.date_title').addClass('displayTitle');
});
```

Comment: try using #dateDeparture instead on using class in jquery

Comment: Thanks your comments. But, still same.. it doesn't work!!

Comment: use $('#dateDeparture') in JS as you have used the class twice in div as well as input field so first time you click its goes to div instead of input field

Comment: made a pluker, there you can see if you click the field the element is added (F12 inspect on browser)... https://plnkr.co/edit/bPiyKfVsTAqOUZmO63p1?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery

```
<script>
$('#dateDeparture').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('dateFocused');
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".date_title").addClass('displayTitle');
});

</script>
```

I am not sure why you want to add `dateFocused` to your input box. However i kept it same. I just changed on `click` event to `focus`.